# FASTAI: 'LSTM' object has no attribute 'out' & attributeerror 'tuple' object has no attribute 'view'

Tags: python, nlp, fast-ai

I received these errors in my NLP model by running fit_one_cycle on a Learner object.
I only managed to come across [This source here](https://www.editcode.net/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=551739&mobile=no&mobile=2) with someone coming across the same problem. It helped me find a solution for me, which I am sharing here in case someone else come across this problem.

The tuple issue is due to the fact that the forward method returns a tuple of three tensors in the FastAI example whereas just a tensor is expected in the `__call__` method. The issued appeared after some update of the functionality, [this seems to be the case](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/issues/3108)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Simply use a `TextLearner` object without specifying the callback methods rather than the `Learner` object (Then the callbacks should automatically be set and these are ajour with functionality). (Recommended)
2. Replace the RNNRegularizer with the correct callback function (requries more customization)

Comment: See this example for context: https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/12_nlp_dive.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

`RNNCallback` should be added in `cbs`.

```
cbs=[ModelResetter, RNNCallback, RNNRegularizer(3,5)]
```